# C fprintf and fscanf saving game state

Tags: c, scanf

I have problem with fscanf and fprintf, i have saved my game state to file, and then tried to load it back from the same file(when i open my program next time)

i have function:

```
bool savegame(saved save) {
    FILE* fptr;
    fptr = fopen("savegame.txt", "w+");
    if (fptr == NULL)
        return 0;
    fprintf(fptr, "beeseed= %d\n", save.beeseed);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fptr, "car %d pos x= %d y=%d\n", i, save.cars[i].pos.x, save.cars[i].pos.y);
        fprintf(fptr, "car %d speed= %d\n", i, save.cars[i].rand);
        fprintf(fptr, "obstacle %d pos x= %d y=%d\n", i, save.obstacles[i].pos.x, save.obstacles[i].pos.y);
        fprintf(fptr, "obstacle %d speed= %d\n", i, save.obstacles[i].rand);
        fprintf(fptr, "frogend %d= %d\n", i, save.frogend[i]);
    }
    fprintf(fptr, "health= %d\n", save.health);
    fprintf(fptr, "worldTime= %f\n", save.worldTime);
    fprintf(fptr, "frog pos x= %d y=%d\n", save.frog.x, save.frog.y);
    fprintf(fptr, "lost frog pos x= %d y= %d rand= %d\n", save.lostfrog.pos.x, save.lostfrog.pos.y, save.lostfrog.rand);
    fprintf(fptr, "score bee= %d score end= %d\n", save.score.bee, save.score.end);
    fprintf(fptr, "score flag= %d score frog= %d\n", save.score.flag, save.score.frog);
    fprintf(fptr, "score pos= %d score total= %d\n", save.score.pos, save.score.total);
    fclose(fptr);
    return 1;
}
```

And this one works great, by that i mean - my file is correctly filled with values.
Now i have tried to do scanning of this file:

```
bool loadgame(saved* save) {
    FILE* fptr;
    fptr = fopen("savegame.txt", "r");
    if (fptr == NULL)
        return 0;
    fscanf(fptr, "beeseed= %d", &save->beeseed);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {

    fscanf(fptr, "car %d pos x= %d y=%d", i, &save->cars[i].pos.x, &save->cars[i].pos.y);
    fscanf(fptr, "car %d speed= %d", i, &save->cars[i].rand);
    fscanf(fptr, "obstacle %d pos x= %d y=%d", i, &save->obstacles[i].pos.x, &save->obstacles[i].pos.y);
    fscanf(fptr, "obstacle %d speed= %d", i, &save->obstacles[i].rand);
    fscanf(fptr, "frogend %d= %d", i, &save->frogend[i]);
    }
    fscanf(fptr, "health= %d", &save->health);
    fscanf(fptr, "worldTime= %lf", &save->worldTime);
    fscanf(fptr, "frog pos x= %d y=%d", &save->frog.x, &save->frog.y);
    fscanf(fptr, "lost frog pos x= %d y= %d rand= %d", &save->lostfrog.pos.x, &save->lostfrog.pos.y, &save->lostfrog.rand);
    fscanf(fptr, "score bee= %d score end= %d", &save->score.bee, &save->score.end);
    fscanf(fptr, "score flag= %d score frog= %d", &save->score.flag, &save->score.frog);
    fscanf(fptr, "score pos= %d score total= %d", &save->score.pos, &save->score.total);
    fclose(fptr);
    return 1;
}
```

and it only works for first line of a file(which is beeseed= 3), the others doesnt work at all

I know i probably do not understand fscanf very well, but i have checked a lot of problems there, on google and i have no idea how to make it correct - and what's most important for me - easy to understand, and readable (i probably could make it all in just one fscanf filled with whole .txt file and variables as %d, but it would look soo messed up)

I have also tried to give '\n' at the end of every fscanf but it brings library error

And my `savegame.txt` file:

```
beeseed= 8
car 0 pos x= 952 y=427
car 0 speed= 9
obstacle 0 pos x= 1028 y=217
obstacle 0 speed= 10
frogend 0= 0
car 1 pos x= 647 y=392
car 1 speed= 8
obstacle 1 pos x= 1131 y=182
obstacle 1 speed= 5
frogend 1= 1
car 2 pos x= 604 y=357
car 2 speed= 5
obstacle 2 pos x= -71 y=147
obstacle 2 speed= 5
frogend 2= 0
car 3 pos x= 437 y=322
car 3 speed= 6
obstacle 3 pos x= 320 y=112
obstacle 3 speed= 7
frogend 3= 0
car 4 pos x= 142 y=287
car 4 speed= 5
obstacle 4 pos x= 7 y=77
obstacle 4 speed= 7
frogend 4= 0
health= 5
worldTime= 4.892000
frog pos x= 320 y=462
lost frog pos x= 376 y= 182 rand= 188
score bee= 200 score end= 476
score flag= 0 score frog= 0
score pos= 0 score total= 120
```

May the problem be that my struct includes boolean `save.frogend[i]` is in boolean form and it takes %d (which is also 1/0)?

```
typedef struct {
int x;
int y;
}pos;

typedef struct {
    short int pos;
    short int end;
    short int frog;
    short int bee;
    short int total;
    short int flag;
} score;

typedef struct {
    bool frogend[5];
    score score;
    pos frog;
    struct {
        pos pos;
        int rand;
    }lostfrog;
    struct {
        pos pos;
        int rand;
    }obstacles[5];
    struct {
        pos pos;
        int rand;
    }cars[5];
    short int beeseed;
    double worldTime;
    int health;
}saved;
```

Comment: I guess there also may be problems with `%d` - one of your struct members may be `long` or `bool` or `char` or `unsigned int`, not `int`. You need to post the definition of `saved` to let others check.

Comment: You forgot about pos.

Comment: You have: `fscanf(fptr, "car %d pos x= %d y=%d", i, &save->cars[i].pos.x, &save->cars[i].pos.y);` — you need to pass `&i` to `fscanf()` (or, rather, some integer variable other than `i`), or suppress the assignment with `%*d`.

Comment: Lidbey, why does code not check the return value of `fscanf()`?

Comment: "tried to give '\n' at the end of every fscanf " was not a bad idea.  Yet a good compiler with warnings enabled would have complained about `fscanf(fptr, "car %d pos x= %d y=%d", i, &save->cars[i].pos.x, &save->cars[i].pos.y);`.  Save time and improve debug speed by enabling all warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not skipping over the newlines in your `fscanf()` format strings. So the second `fscanf()` will fail because it expects to find the word `car` immediately after the last `y=%d`, but there's a newline between them.

Put a space at the beginning of each format string. That will make it skip over any leading whitespace.

Also, all the `i` in the arguments should be `&i`. But you don't really want to reassign `i`, since it's controlled by the `for` loop header. So you should just skip assigning those fields to any variable; you can do this with `%*d`.

```
bool loadgame(saved* save) {
    FILE* fptr;
    fptr = fopen("savegame.txt", "r");
    if (fptr == NULL)
        return 0;
    fscanf(fptr, "beeseed= %d", &save->beeseed);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {

        fscanf(fptr, " car %*d pos x= %d y=%d", &save->cars[i].pos.x, &save->cars[i].pos.y);
        fscanf(fptr, " car %*d speed= %d", &save->cars[i].rand);
        fscanf(fptr, " obstacle %*d pos x= %d y=%d", &save->obstacles[i].pos.x, &save->obstacles[i].pos.y);
        fscanf(fptr, " obstacle %*d speed= %d", &save->obstacles[i].rand);
        fscanf(fptr, " frogend %*d= %d", &save->frogend[i]);
    }
    fscanf(fptr, " health= %d", &save->health);
    fscanf(fptr, " worldTime= %lf", &save->worldTime);
    fscanf(fptr, " frog pos x= %d y=%d", &save->frog.x, &save->frog.y);
    fscanf(fptr, " lost frog pos x= %d y= %d rand= %d", &save->lostfrog.pos.x, &save->lostfrog.pos.y, &save->lostfrog.rand);
    fscanf(fptr, " score bee= %d score end= %d", &save->score.bee, &save->score.end);
    fscanf(fptr, " score flag= %d score frog= %d", &save->score.flag, &save->score.frog);
    fscanf(fptr, " score pos= %d score total= %d", &save->score.pos, &save->score.total);
    fclose(fptr);
    return 1;
}
```

Another option would be to read each line using `fgets()`, and then use `sscanf()` to extract values from it.

Comment: I've updated the answer. You weren't taking the address of `i` when scanning into it.

Comment: consider scanning into a temporary variable and checking the value equals `i`. Also some other method of error detection would be appropriate (e.g. a sentinel string after the last line would be less messy than checking every fscanf return value)

Comment: @M.M I actually considered rewriting it to scan `i` separately, then scan into `&save->XXX[i].YYY`. But it seemed more complex than necessary to help the OP, and unnecessary if it's guaranteed that the data is written in order.

Comment: Thank you, it works very well with this spaces and problem with `i`, I thought that if i pass `i` without `&` sign it won't try to pass any value

Comment: Why would you think that? `fscanf()` can't tell the difference, it will try to use the value as the address to write to.

Answer (score 3):

1. Handle `fscanf` return value. Handle errors.
2. You can't scan into `i`. Enable compiler warnings and fix them.
3. As in the other answer, scan newline.
4. The format specifier for `short int` is `%hd`.

As for point 2, doing `fscanf(fptr, "%d", i)` is invalid, `i` is not a valid address of a variable.  With `%*d` you can scan for one integer without saving the result:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    int e = fscanf(fptr, " car %*d pos x= %d y=%d", &save->cars[i].pos.x, &save->cars[i].pos.y); 
    if (e != 2) abort();
    ...
}
```

But I would implement as pendantic error handling as you can:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    int read_i = 0;
    int e = fscanf(fptr, " car %d pos x= %d y=%d", &read_i, &save->cars[i].pos.x, &save->cars[i].pos.y); 
    if (e != 3) abort(); // handle error
    if (i != read_i) abort(); // handle error
    ...
}
```

> May the problem be that my struct includes boolean save.frogend[i] is in boolean form

For example if the type of `save.frongend[i]` is `bool`, you need to scan into temporary variable with proper type to match the `scanf` specifier. You could use `%d` with just `int`, for example. And then check if the values are in proper ranges. For example:

```
int temp = 0;
int e = fscanf(fptr, "frogend %*d= %d", &temp);
if (e != 1) abort();
if (temp != 0 && temp != 1) abort();
save->frogend[i] = temp;
```

I guess putting it all together:

```
bool loadgame(saved* save) {
    FILE* fptr;
    fptr = fopen("savegame.txt", "r");
    if (fptr == NULL)
        return 0;
    int e = 0;
    e = fscanf(fptr, "beeseed= %hd", &save->beeseed);
    if (e != 1) return 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int i2 = 0;
        e = fscanf(fptr, " car %d pos x= %d y=%d", &i2, &save->cars[i].pos.x, &save->cars[i].pos.y);
        if (e != 3) return 0;
        if (i2 != i) return 0;
        e = fscanf(fptr, " car %d speed= %d", &i2, &save->cars[i].rand);
        if (e != 2) return 0;
        if (i2 != i) return 0;
        e = fscanf(fptr, " obstacle %d pos x= %d y=%d", &i2, &save->obstacles[i].pos.x, &save->obstacles[i].pos.y);
        if (e != 3) return 0;
        if (i2 != i) return 0;
        e = fscanf(fptr, " obstacle %d speed= %d", &i2, &save->obstacles[i].rand);
        if (e != 2) return 0;
        if (i2 != i) return 0;
        int temp = 0;
        e = fscanf(fptr, "frogend %d= %d", &i2, &temp);
        if (e != 2) return 0;
        if (i2 != i) return 0;
        if (temp != 0 && temp != 1) return 0;
        save->frogend[i] = temp;
    }
    e = fscanf(fptr, " health= %d", &save->health);
    if (e != 1) return 0;
    e = fscanf(fptr, " worldTime= %lf", &save->worldTime);
    if (e != 1) return 0;
    e = fscanf(fptr, " frog pos x= %d y=%d", &save->frog.x, &save->frog.y);
    if (e != 2) return 0;
    e = fscanf(fptr, " lost frog pos x= %d y= %d rand= %d", &save->lostfrog.pos.x, &save->lostfrog.pos.y, &save->lostfrog.rand);
    if (e != 3) return 0;
    e = fscanf(fptr, " score bee= %hd score end= %hd", &save->score.bee, &save->score.end);
    if (e != 2) return 0;
    e = fscanf(fptr, " score flag= %hd score frog= %hd", &save->score.flag, &save->score.frog);
    if (e != 2) return 0;
    e = fscanf(fptr, " score pos= %hd score total= %hd", &save->score.pos, &save->score.total);
    if (e != 2) return 0;
    fclose(fptr);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now very well, but i still get warnings about not well assigned types, as long as i have checked that i can write %h instead of %d to assign short int type, i do not know what is the flag for bool type??

Comment: And is it correct - as you suggested (you're probably advanced programmer so i feel like it's just a moment for you to answer) to write `if(numofresults!='predicted value') return 0;` ? i mean, doesn't it make code too much messy?

Comment: It's `%hd` to assign to `short int`. There is no flag for `boo`, so you need to use other type. If you really want to, you can use `%hhd` and `char`, but really, makes no difference then `%d`. Error handling in C is verbose. It is verbose and there is nothing wrong with that. I think I'm just used to write `if` after each statement I make. I believe you meant to write `if(numofresults!='predicted value') return 0;`

Comment: I see it doesn't make difference because it's working great, but how to get rid of 50 warnings then, after assigning those values?

Comment: One warning at a time!

Comment: I'm on polish version at Visual Studio, but will try to translate it: `incompability of size short shown as _Param(3), when there is needed element '32 bit operand' in element fscanf - it shows a potentially serious problem, it can make overflow of buffer`

Comment: Most probably from what you showed you need to \change most your `%d` into `%hd`. Go through all the `scanf` statements and change them. So, go to the line of the warning, see which `%<something>` specifier does the param 3 refer to, and fix it. All vars inside `score` are `signed int`. It _may_ be working great, but it invokes undefined behavior, and undefined behavior may work great. Most probably it will start failing with greater values or it corrupts some other regions of memory. And, as for me, I'm polish ; )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205559/discussion-between-lidbey-and-kamilcuk).